# svncl.info2() function does not return an object

Tags: svn, pysvn

I am trying to get the author and the last update date by using the following code

```
log = svncl.info2(Path, 
    revision=pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.head),
    peg_revision=pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.head))
for info in log:    
    User_Name = info.author
    timestamp = info.date
```

This function `svncl.info2()` does not return an object.
**What changes are to be made to return an object?**
If invoked on command line, `svn info Path`, it displays the last update return information.

Comment: Presumably you left out a line reading: 
svncl = pysvn.Client()
info2 should be returning a dictionary.

Comment: i have mentioned "svncl = pysvn.Client()" in my actual code

Comment: But not in the sample above - so I had to guess!

Answer (score 0):

The `pysvn client info2` method will either return a list of `info2` objects or `None` - if you are getting `None` the most likely problem is a trust issue - this can be resolved by setting the callback members up especially `callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt` try adding:

```
def ssl_server_trust_prompt( trust_dict ):
    return True, 0, True
svncl.callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt = ssl_server_trust_prompt
```